# How to use enum array in mysql as TypeORM

Tags: mysql, arrays, enums, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using NestJS and I'm making an entity with typeorm.
There was a problem when creating a role for user.entity.

If you make it like the attached code, you will get mysql syntax error as below.(There is no typeorm syntax error in the code stage.) Because mysql does not support enum arrays.

```
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity extends CoreEntity {
  ...

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: Role,
    array: true,
    default: [Role.User],
  })
  @IsString()
  public roles!: Role[];

  ...
}
```

query failed: ALTER TABLE `user` ADD `roles` enum array ('User', 'Admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'User'
error:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'array ('User', 'Admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'User'' at line 1

I thought several solution.

1. Change RDBMS to Postgres that support enum array.
2. Separate the Role table and join with User, N:M.
3. Save as string type and inject the split transform when loading.
4. I turn it into an object and save it as a json type.

I am wondering what is the right solution...

Comment: The `array` keyword is obviously errorneous in SQL code.. are you sure that `array: true` is correct? ENUM datatype is scalar one.

Comment: Maybe this is a characteristic of DBMS. I think DBMS that supports arrays such as postgres in typeform is also available.

Comment: ORM does not distinguish does DBMS supports array datatype or not? I'd recommend to use another ORM.. those which at least produces a message that current DBMS does not support this property..

Comment: I think so too... can you recommend other ORM?